# Get the image url from string

Tags: string

My string is: [slide image="http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uploadify/uploads/bas_006.jpg" slide_desc="

How to get the part after "image=" from it?

Comment: What language are you using/ What have you tried?

Comment: replace [slide image=" and " slide_desc=" with a blank char ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, use RegEx to get the data between 2 strings. For the most part, the same Reg Expressions between different languages should work just fine.

In PHP, you would want to use a preg_match.

```
$string = "[slide image=\"http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uploadify/uploads/bas_006.jpg\" slide_desc=\""
preg_match("/image=\"(.*)\"/i", $string, $results)
var_dump($results)
```

Update regex (a little more strict):

```
/image\="([^"]*)"/i
```

All in all, going to depend on the language being used and in what context. You can get much more advanced with the RegEx, but this is just quick & dirty.

[image]

Full PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$string = '[slide image="http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uplo‌​adify/uploads/bas_006.jpg" slide_desc="<h4>Promotional Package</h4> Project description sentence" text_color="#464646" slide_horizontal="false"] [slide image="http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uplo‌​adify/uploads/bas_005.jpg" slide_desc="<h4></h4>" text_color="#464646" slide_horizontal="false"]';
preg_match_all('/image\="([^"]*)"/i', $string, $results);
foreach ($results[1] as $res):
  echo 'Image URL:'.$res."\n";
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: It's ok, but what when i have for example this code:

`[slide image="http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uploadify/uploads/bas_006.jpg" slide_desc="<h4>Promotional Package</h4>
Project description sentence" text_color="#464646" slide_horizontal="false"]
[slide image="http://themes.devatic.com/konzept/wp-content/themes/konzept/includes/uploadify/uploads/bas_005.jpg" slide_desc="<h4></h4>" text_color="#464646" slide_horizontal="false"]`

And how to get all image url's from it.

Comment: You would use the PHP Function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php (if you are using PHP)

Comment: updated regex code and added screen shot for you. You can also test regex code -- I use the site above, all the time. www.rubular.com

Comment: Ok, but how to use it? I've got code `$slides = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slides', false);

preg_match('/image\="([^"]*)"', $slides, $results);
var_dump($results);`

And i get Null

Comment: Added full code example. Make sure your $slides is a STRING, not an object or array.